# How to save LDA model - LatentDirichletAllocation in python

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

I have trained a LDA model using below command, need to understand how to save it.

```
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=25, random_state=100)
```

I have tried the below method, but it is saying

AttributeError: 'LatentDirichletAllocation' object has no attribute 'save'

```
lda_model.save("xyz.model")
```

It took 16 hours to train the model. Re-creating it will be very time consuming. Any advise will be really appreciated!

Comment: I Googled "save scikit learn model" and this came up https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html. I haven't read it, but should be a good start. Generally, it's better to generalize your questions when searching ("save scikit learn model") vs something too specific. Also in general you can save python objects by pickling them https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Models are serializable in scikit-learn, thus you can save it with:

```py
import pickle

pickle.dump(lda_model, 'lda_model.pk')
# then reload it with
lda_model = pickle.load('lda_model.pk')
```

Note that, according to the doc, you may want to prefer `joblib` when model contains large estimators

```
import joblib

joblib.dump(lda_model, 'lda_model.jl')
# then reload it with
lda_model = joblib.load('lda_model.jl')
```

As mentioned by Michael Silverstein, it is documented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Comment: Thank you, was not aware of it. :)